# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' while deploying create react app to firebase hosting

Tags: reactjs, firebase, create-react-app, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy my app to firebase hosting and I'm getting this error in the console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` in several `*.chunk.js` files. I have already deployed [my app to gh-pages](https://nayakunin.github.io/pr-mebel/#/) and everything has worked just fine. Also I have tried to deploy it to netlify hosting but I had `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()` in all *.js files.
Here is my `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {"source": "/service-worker.js", "headers": [{"key": "Cache-Control", "value": "no-cache"}]}
    ]
  }
}
```

For some reason these `*.chunk.js` files contain some html code
[image from the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qckY0.png)
But at the same time my local `main.chunk.js` does not
[image of local file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xhU6.png)

Comment: The problem is not with the Firebase Hosting configuration you're showing here. It's with the content that you deployed.

Comment: But how is it working on gh-pages then? What might be the difference between them?

Comment: If you have more information to share about your observations, I suggest editing the question to include everything.  Without specific source code and steps to take to reproduce the problem, I don't think there's much we can do.

Comment: Added link to broken firebase app and screenshots of `main.chunk.js`. Thanks for advise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, I had a conflict in my `package.json` file. Necessary for `gh-pages` `"homepage": ...` in `package.json` was somehow messing up with deployments to other hosting providers.